# Having a problem with Laravel Eloquent in query date format transformation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am using laravel to make a query and return all results that match several criteria. One of them is by date, the problem is that I
store dates in the database in this format:

2021-03-26 12:20:00

and display them in this format:

March 26, 2021

It is a requirement for the project that if you search: March 26

All items with that given month and day are returned

This needs to be done in the query itself, because I also use pagination and other search and orderBy criteria

I am using this:

{...}

```
$attrDate = 'appointment.date';
$query->orWhereDate($attrDate, 'LIKE', ["%{$search}%"]);
$query->orderBy('appointment.date', $order)->take($pagination)->skip($skip);  
$appointments=$query->get();
```

{...}

That works if I search for numbers cointained in the appointment dates (26, 2021...)

But I also want to be able to search by month in string format, like 'March 26' or 'March 26, 2021' and show appointments for that given date. There is where I get the errors when I try this:

```
$attrDate = 'appointment.date';
$date_transform= "DATE_FORMAT({$attrDate}, '%F%j,%Y')";   
$query->orWhereDate($date_transform, 'LIKE', ["%{$search}%"]);
```

It returns a code 500 response with an sql error.

I don't know what to do, since all of this are requirements for the project and I can't really change them. I have searched in the Laravel documentation, but I have not found anything that can help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my case, I would search normal, with the laravel timestap format, but when returning the results, I format it with a getter. Likewise when I go to do the search: I format the values to my format while the user thinks it will search as they want it. But i don't know this work for you

Answer (score 0):

Laravel have also eloquent methods `whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear / whereTime`, so you can use any of them.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '12')
            ->get();
```

Source: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using carbon's parser like e.g.

```
$attrDate = 'appointment.date';
$dateSearch = Carbon::parse($search);
$query->orWhereDate($attrDate, $dateSearch);
$query->orderBy('appointment.date', $order)->take($pagination)->skip($skip);  
$appointments=$query->get();
```

This offloads the issue to Carbon's date parsing (which is pretty good). The issue here is it will assume the year rather than searching for any year

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I ended up using custom casts because the user must be able to search by string, and the search string might not be a valid date, just a part of it.